# How to jump focus on the second textbox when value of first textbox is maxLenght=3

Tags: javascript, textbox, focus, maxlength, onkeypress

I have 2 textboxes next to each other for the Telephone number field on an Online Request form.

The maxLenght of the first textbox is = 3, so after the user has entered in the value it must focus on the second textbox.

I added this function to my input type textbox, but it only allows one value and then it already focuses on the second textbox.

```
onkeypress="if(value.lenght==3)return false;
            document.getElementById('TelNumber2').focus();"
```

I tried this function too but the same happens

```
onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==3)return false;
            document.getElementById('TelNumber2').focus();"
```

These are my textboxes:

First textbox:

```
input type="textbox" id="TelNumber1" name="TelNumber1" value="" maxLenght="3" 
style="width:40px; border: 1px solid #b5b6b5" size="3" 
onKeyDown="limitText(this,3);" onKeyUp="MaxText(this,3);" />
```

Second textbox:

```
input type="textbox" id="TelNumber2" name="TelNumber2" value="" maxLenght="7"
style="width:115px; border: 1px solid #b5b6b5" size="7" 
onKeyDown="MaxText(this,7);" onKeyUp="MaxText(this,7);" />
```

Will appreciate any help

Camerone

Comment: You spelled length incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You just spelled length incorrectly. This works fine.

```
<input onkeyup='if (this.value.length >= 3) { document.getElementById("TelNumber2").focus(); }' />
```

EDIT: I stand corrected. It looks like when the code is in the attribute like that, you do not need to use `this`. `value` is already in scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning back before you set the focus. So, your code to set the focus, i.e. `document.getElementById('TelNumber2').focus();` is not being called at all.

Try the following. Don't use the return statement.

```
onkeypress="if(value.length==3) document.getElementById('TelNumber2').focus();"
```

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 

I removed the return statement, but now it doesn't even jump focus to the next textbox anymore. It just stays in the first textbox

The function now looks like this;

onkeypress="if(value.lenght==3) document.getElementById('TelNumber2').focus();"

used this one too

onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==3) document.getElementById('TelNumber2').focus(); "